# External tables in Kusto - Cross tenant ADLS storage account as data source

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azure-data-explorer, kql, azure-synapse

I have an ADLS storage account in tenant X and a multi tenant App registration that has read access to the ADLS storage account.
The storage account has terabytes of data coming in daily.
So I figured copy activity to Kusto in tenant Y through Synapse is a worse choice.

Then i came to know about external tables in Kusto. But my Kusto cluster in tenant Y does not have access to ADLS account in tenant X.
I want to use my multi tenant App registration from tenant X for Kusto to authenticate itself to the ADLS and read data through external tables.
How to achieve this?
Is there any docs on this?

if this is not possible, how do people transfer terabytes of data from one tenant to another tenant's kusto cluster?

Comment: **(1)** What benefit do you think you would you get from using external table? **(2)** A key principles in multitenant architnecture is to keep separation between different tenants. Copying data between tenants seems quite strange in this context.

Comment: I get your point, but it is something totally required in our case, I cannot avoid it. 
For the benefit, I believe it removes my overhead of setting up copy activities through synapse, moving data back in, and then querying again.

Comment: Not sure I follow. You plan to query the external table, defined in cluster X, with your application and then ingest the data to cluster Y, using the SDK?

Answer (score 0):

You could consider using [Azure Data Share](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-share/supported-data-stores#supported-data-stores) or [Purview Data Share](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/azure/purview/concept-data-share#where-data-is-stored) that supports in-place sharing of ADLS data across orgs subject to T&Cs being created by owner and accepted by receiver.
This would provide separation of concerns, accurate charge-back, and you end up with a tenant local abfss connection string.
Worth looking into the performance characteristics of such a set up.